# How to focus on a button after a text digited on a input field?

Tags: javascript, html

I already searched here and find some solutions with `focus()`,I tryied to adapte this function to my code but unsuccessfully, just want to `focus()` a button after a text digited in the input tag with 6 max lenght, then auto press enter, to send the data

```
$("#PopID-Lido").keyup(function () {
    debugger
        if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
          $(this).next('#senData').focus();
        }
  });
```

I not try to auto press enter because I get stucked with this...
html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container-popid" for="PopID-Lido">POPID ATUAL <!--<span id="actPopid"> </span> -->

        <form>
            <input type="text" id='PopID-Lido' class='PopID-atual PopID-Lido' maxlength="6">

        </form>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="container-NextPopID" for='Next-PopID'>PRÓXIMO POPID 
         <output type="text" id="NextPopID" class='Next-PopID NextPopID'>  
    </div>

</div>

<br><input type="button" id="senData" value="Send to PLC">
```

Comment: If your target is press the button to submit the form, why not to send the form instead of clicking the button ? If you dont want to send the form, why do you have a form ?

Comment: I have to use a button because the data in the input tag is send to a PLC, and this feature needs a function like click to send, this can't be write inside the plc, without this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dom selector is wrong here. try like this or use the proper selector.

```
$("#PopID-Lido").keyup(function () {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      $('#senData').focus();
    }
});
```